# How to pass data between two activities

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have a `NetworkList` class which has a `arraylist` of type `string`.  I am using parcelable interface in it.but i am getting only the first element of `arraylist` in my new activity.
how can i get all the elements?
here is NetworkList class

```
public class NetworkList implements Parcelable{
private ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> id=new ArrayList<String>();



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public NetworkList(Parcel in) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    name=in.readArrayList(null);
    id=in.readArrayList(null);
}



public NetworkList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



public void setName(String tempValue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.name.add(tempValue);
}



public void setid(String tempValue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.id.add(tempValue);
}



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeList(name);
    dest.writeList(id);
}



public ArrayList<String> getname() {
    return name;
}

public static final Creator<NetworkList> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<NetworkList>() {
    public NetworkList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new NetworkList(in);
    }

    public NetworkList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new NetworkList[size];
    }

};
}
```

here is how where i pass it

```
Intent(AllNetworkActivity.this,WorkActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",network);
            startActivity(intent);
    }});



}
```

here is how i retrieve it

```
   Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    NetworkList network=(NetworkList)extras.getParcelable("name");
    String name[]=new String[network.getname().size()];
    for(int i=0;i<network.getname().size();i++){
        name[i]=network.getname().get(i);
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.work,name));
```

hope u are able to help me know

Comment: i have posted the code..i am just getting the first element of arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also look into Application class in Android. You can define global variables in there which can be accessed by all activities. However Bundle is the most popular and right method for sending data between activities.

Answer (score 0):

Try using appropriate methods to serialize `List<String>`:

```
public NetworkList(Parcel in) {
    in.readStringList(name);
    in.readStringList(id);
}


public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // log the number of elements - check that this is actually what you expect it to be
    // use only during development
    Log.i("NetworkList"," number of elements = "+name.size())

    dest.writeStringList(name);
    dest.writeStringList(id);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the number of elements before you write them to parcel? The `Log.i()` line?

Comment: actually i do not know how to check that.thanks for ur answer

Comment: where can i see the no. of elements...I heard it for first time

Comment: You were saying that your list had only one element when received (deserialized). How many elements did it have when serialized in `writeToParcel()`?

Comment: i have posted all my code.hope you can help my know.thanks for ur efffort

Comment: You need to ask specific questions. I'm not willing to debug your code.

Comment: the problem is same that i am getting just a single element in listview while there are 3.

Answer (score 0):

first

```
Intent Jan = new Intent(Months.this,Holiday.class);   
                    Jan.putExtra("ListCount", "Jan");   
                  startActivity(Jan);
```

then

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String data = extras.getString("ListCount");

        if(data.equals("Jan")){
            TextView txtMonth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMonth);
            txtMonth.setText("January");

            TextView txtDetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDetail);
            txtDetail.setText(R.string.JanHol);
        }
```

[check this post](http://android.mayuonline.com/2011/05/20/passing-data-with-intent/) I wrote. Hope this will help you.